# neo4j: getting data out of, and ordering on, node properties when the property holds an array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with a property called 'flavors' which includes tuples of data like this:

```
node1.flavors = {"cherry":174,"vanilla":105,"chocolate":60}
node2.flavors = {"cherry":17,"vanilla":10,"chocolate":300}
```

I want to find the node with the highest integer associated with chocolate, which would be node2.  How can I do this?

I figured out how to use a regex to get those where chocolate is in the flavors property:

```
start n=node(*)
WHERE has(n.flavors) AND n.flavors =~ '.*chocolate.*'
RETURN count(n);
```

Now I just need to get the number after "chocolate":*_*.

MORE INFO:
It's a JSON string.  If I can't deal with it in cypher I'll have to deal with it in Ruby and re-do the data model in neo4j.  I believe I can't use substring because we don't have an indexOf function on properties, right?

```
2.0.0p247 :002 > r = JSON.parse('{"vanilla":161,"chocolate":21,"cherry":18}')
 => {"vanilla"=>161, "chocolate"=>21, "cherry"=>18} 
2.0.0p247 :004 > r.class
 => Hash 
2.0.0p247 :005 > r.keys
 => ["vanilla", "chocolate", "cherry"] 
2.0.0p247 :006 > r.values
 => [161, 21, 18] 
2.0.0p247 :007 > r["vanilla"]
 => 161
```

Comment: Is the flavors property a string that you know is an array. Or is it actually an array?  Your example above shows it as a property-map which I don't think is supported.  Your query indicates that it is possibly a string.

Comment: @LameCoder you are correct that neo4j doesn't support property maps. How are you inserting that property?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply store the different flavors as separate properties ? You could then simply do : where has(n.chocolate) return n.chocolate

Comment: We cannot store the different flavors as separate properties because we don't know what the flavors will be.  there are potentially hundreds of flavors.

Comment: @Darby If there are hundres of flavors, you could make each flavor a node of its own, then put the numbers on relationships between node1 above (etc) and the flavor nodes.

Answer (score 3):

The query you provide will check every single node in the graph, which will get slow as the size of the graph increases. You're trying to use Cypher to do string manipulation, while Cypher is first and foremost a language to query the graph. It would seem to me you're either using the wrong datastore or your not modelling it usefully for a graph. Why not make the nodes (recipies?) and flavours entities and connect them with a relationship that has a property on how much of the flavour they have? Then you can query them easily and efficiently. I've quickly modelled this here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/tp355x (uses Cypher/Neo4j 2.0).

So, the answer to the question would be not to try to use Cyhper for something it wasn't really made for, but redo the model in your Ruby code like demoed above.

If you need inspiration on how to represent data in a graph, there are [Graph Gists](http://gist.neo4j.org) to give you some ideas perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for that jotomo.  I'm actually trying to revamp our data model as you suggested!  I'd like to, for each 'recipe' node (that already exists), create a node for each flavor, and create a relationship between the 'recipe' and the flavor, and have as a property on the rel, the amount, just as you have demonstrated in the gist.  I'm having a hard time, then, getting to the data in the current model, in order to create the new model.